# any tricky way to get image `path:tag` inside a running container

Tags: docker, containers

Whether if there's any tricky to get current image `path:tag` inside a running container.

i.e.:

```
$ docker run -it 'ubuntu:18.04' bash
root@<cid> $                  <- how to show the 'ubuntu:18.04'
```

Comment: No, there isn't a way to get this.

Comment: I can be sure I've seen some commands for check running image before, pretty sure on that. and I've tried in Kuberentes pods successful, a very simeple cmd, but just cannot remember it